# Python function to append new data into my existing csv files

Tags: python, pandas, function, pandas-datareader

1. I would like to add code allowing me to update my stock files without having to redownload all the data but just append the new data to my existing csv files. Thank you in advance and sorry for my summary.

```
 def save_sp500_tickers():
     resp = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_S%26P_500_companies')
     soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(resp.text, 'lxml')
     table = soup.find('table', {'class':'wikitable sortable'})
     tickers = []
     for row in table.findAll('tr')[1:]:
         ticker = row.findAll('td')[0].text.replace('.','').strip()
         tickers.append(ticker)
     with open("sp500tickers.pickle","wb") as f:
         pickle.dump(tickers, f)

     return tickers

 #save_sp500_tickers()

 def get_data(reload_sp500=False):
     if reload_sp500:
         tickers = save_sp500_tickers()
     else:
         with open("sp500tickers.pickle","rb") as f:
             tickers = pickle.load(f)

     if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs'):
         os.makedirs('stock_dfs')
     start = dt.datetime(2019,1,1)
     end = dt.datetime(2019,8,1)

     for ticker in tickers:
         if not os.path.exists('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker)):
             df = web.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start, end)
             df.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
         else:
             print('Already have {}'.format(ticker))

 get_data()
```

Answer (score 1):

The [to_csv()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) function has a `mode` parameter. Set that to `mode='a'` and you will append data to the CSV, not overwrite

Update:
To check whether you already have the data, you will need to read the data into a dataframe, and only include rows which are not found in the dataframe.

```py
import pandas as pd
for ticker in tickers: 
    df = pd.read_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker))
    df_net_new = df[df["Ticker"] != ticker ]
    df_net_new.to_csv('stock_dfs/{}.csv'.format(ticker), mode='a')
```

Difficult to solve this without more information, but I hope this helps.

Comment: Shouldn't it be quoted?

Comment: Thank you for the catch ! yes, string type

Comment: instead of else: print already have the ticker, I would like a way to pull the data and add it to my existing files.  I tried what you said but i get errors.

Comment: Glad to hear :) Feel free to mark the answer if it helped you.